# SED - complex text deletion and pattern matching

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

I searched allot on SED. I'm new to using it. Managed to make a command that deletes a block of text between PATTERN-1 and PATTERN-2 (including the patterns) in a large (250mb+) text file.

Now I have a much more complex task. I need to find a pattern in the text file, and delete all the text from the a line BEFORE the pattern, up to another line matching another pattern. I will give an example:

```
PATTERN-1 = '<connection'
PATTERN-2 = state="wreck"
PATTERN-3 = '</connection>'
```

I need to search for PATTERN-2. IE: state="wreck"
When I find PATTERN-2, I need to find the PREVIOUS PATTERN-1.
Then I need to delete all text between PATTERN-1 and PATTERN-3 (which would include deleting PATTERN-2).

So if my text is:

```
<connection ...
... state="wreck" ...
</connection>
```

I would find any instances of state="wreck" - and then delete everything between
`<connection` and `</connection>` (including the text `<connection` and `</connection>`).

Thank you. Hope this is a clear question.

Comment: btw the pattern matching i used previously to delete text between 2 blocks worked fine.
it was simply:
  `sed '/^<discovered>/,/<\/discovered>/d' file1 > file2`
problem now is that I need to find another string inside of a block, and then delete the containing block.

Comment: [This](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html) is a good introduction to both basic and more advanced features of `sed`, including multi-line handling.

Comment: I don't know if `sed` will be the fastest filter for this, but this is a way to do it `sed -r '/<connection/ { :a; N; /\/connection/ { /wreck/ {d}; p;d }; ba}'`

Comment: Hi Paulo, this is not working completely either. It deletes much more than the containing block with `state="wreck"`. IE: it deletes more before the previous `<connection` pattern. It also leaves empty lines, but thats easy to fix with another sed command so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go if you're OK to use perl, this removes all blocks `<connection...</connection>` that include `state="wreck"`

```
cat file.txt
blah blah
<connection ...
... state="wreck" ...
</connection>
blah blah
<connection ...
... state="wreck" ...
</connection>
blah blah
blah blah
<connection ...
... state="another" ...
</connection>
blah blah
<connection ...
... state="wreck" ...
</connection>
blah blah

perl -0 -pe 's#<connection(?:(?!</connection>).)*state="wreck"(?:(?!</connection>).)*</connection>##gs' file.txt
blah blah

blah blah

blah blah
blah blah
<connection ...
... state="another" ...
</connection>
blah blah

blah blah
```

**Explanation:**

```
-0      # slurp mode, read the file as it has only 1 line
-pe     # print current line, execute the following instructions
```

**Regex:**

```
s#                      : substitute, regex delimiter
<connection             : literally
(?:                     : start non capture group
    (?!</connection>)   : negative lookahead, make sure we don't find </connection>
    .                   : any character, including newline because of the s flag
)*                      : group may appear 0 or more times
state="wreck"           : literally
(?:                     : start non capture group
    (?!</connection>)   : negative lookahead, make sure we don't find </connection>
    .                   : any character, including newline because of the s flag
)*                      : group may appear 0 or more times
</connection>           : literally
##gs                    : replace with empty string, global, dot match newline
```

Comment: thanks! the sed command suggested above also worked.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working!
There are 2 issues.

1 - it is leaving empty lines. Can easily fix with sed. np.

2 - it is deleting much more than the block containing `state="wreck"`
It is deleting from 2 previous matches of `<connection` rather than just the previous match.

Also, if it helps - the structure is like this:
`<connection ....
... state="wreck" ...
...
</connection>`

The line with `<connection ...` is always 1 line before the line with `state="wreck"`, so maybe just deleting from the previous line rather than pattern matching previous?